# ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect breaks while connecting to redis server

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-server, redisclient

I successfully installed the Redis server on my Windows 7 machine.
Did a quick hands on, everything works as expected.
(installed using the MSI installer from https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis )

I am using the StackExchange redis client C# for connecting to Redis server.
[RedisClient](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis)

P.S. : I did not build the application on my machine as I am having VS 2010 and that was throwing some error. So i installed the nuget package and now my Test App in C# has the assembly **StackExchange.Redis**

[image]

My console app is simple with just one line of code

```
    ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379,allowAdmin=true");
```

It gives me an error :

```
System.AggregateException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
       at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImpl(Func`1 multiplexerFactory, TextWriter log) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 817
       at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(String configuration, TextWriter log) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 795
       at testapp.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\_Work\TestApp\Program.cs:line 64
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Security.VerificationException
       HResult=-2146233075
       Message=Method System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[System.Boolean].AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted: type argument 'Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[StackExchange.Redis.ServerEndPoint]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TAwaiter'.
       Source=StackExchange.Redis
       StackTrace:
            at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.<ReconfigureAsync>d__2d.MoveNext()
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
            at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ReconfigureAsync(Boolean first, Boolean reconfigureAll, TextWriter log, EndPoint blame, String cause, Boolean publishReconfigure, CommandFlags publishReconfigureFlags)
            at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.<>c__DisplayClass29.<ConnectImpl>b__26() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 815
            at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
            at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
       InnerException:
```

Comment: I got the same error. Thought it´s because I use SharpDevelop, but seems to be not an issue of the IDE. But no solution so far...

Comment: you mean while building ? because i am talking of using the dll and instantiating the client in a console application .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles on this the cause is a version mismatch with the Microsoft.Bcl package. Run the command `Update-Package Microsoft.Bcl` to resolve.

see http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/03/so-i-went-and-wrote-another-redis-client.html?showComment=1405397410965#c8649668071319126908